# arraylist in c# reading and combo boxes

Tags: c#

i am having trouble figuring out how to get this to work. I basically need load the lines from a .txt file and add each line separately to the Arraylist.
Here is what i have so far, it works but they all come out on one line when i populate the combo box.
I will appreciate any help/tips

```
public void LoadArrayList()
{
snip
}
```

Comment: You could start by indenting your code properly. You'll find it a lot easier to read, and so will everyone else, which makes it easier to help you.

Comment: Thanks Blogbeard, will try keep that in mind :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can do as below

```
cboActor.Items.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filename));
```

what you currently doing is reading all the text as one item and then adding it to combobox.

```
public void LoadArrayList()
{
    ActorArrayList.AddRange(File.ReadAllLines(filename));
}

public void PopulateActors()
{
  cboActor.Items.Clear();
  cboActor.Items.AddRange(ActorArrayList.ToArray());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Damith, Although i seem to be getting an error now with the do/while loop. Will try to sort that out quickly and test.